# JPA predicate in queries

Tags: jpa

I have a route class,  in this class, I defined a collection of locations.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "route_location_map")
    private List<Location> locations;
```

What I required is to check a particular location is present in my route

```
 if (locationId != null && locationId.longValue() > 0) {
                 Expression<Collection<Long>> locations = route.get("locations").get("id");

                 predicate = builder.isMember(locationId, locations);

                whereClauseList.add(predicate);
```

Unfortunately, this logic is not working, I didn't get any error too.
Can anybody help me to resolve this?

Comment: "is not working"? The log for your JPA provider tells you what exactly? The equivalent JPQL ? the SQL invoked?

Comment: also the route.get.get line is flawed ... it will give you an expression for the "id" field of Location, not a Collection of ids!

Answer (score 0):

Post next your stacktrace. You need to use isMember() with your Entity or Expression.

```
public List<Route> findRoutes(Location location){
    ...
    Expression<Collection<Location>> locations = route.get("locations");
    predicate = builder.isMember(location, locations);
    ...
}
```